# Getting Exchange Rates for Historical and Using Today's Rate for Future Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There is a table A which has Start and End Date, Price and CurrencyCode. 
There is a table B which has historical + Today's Exchange Rates. 
I need to convert table A Price based on the following assumptions:

- For the Historical Dates (I.e Start & End Date) < Today's Date, I
  will get their average exchange rate and use that for the conversion.
- Any future Date (Date > Today) will use today's exchange rate.

Esentially, I need to get an average Exchange Rate for the Duration of the WeekStart - WeekEnd Date.

Here is a schema/ some sample data for Table B which contains the Exchange Rate.

```
    DateTime                     Date       FromCurrCode  ToCurrCode   Rate
    2016-07-07 07:16:12.000       2016-07-07    USD        CAD         1.2939
    2016-07-06 07:27:12.000       2016-07-06    USD        CAD         1.3017
    2016-07-05 07:34:07.000       2016-07-05    USD        CAD         1.2922
    2016-07-04 07:42:07.000       2016-07-04    USD        CAD         1.2853
    2016-07-03 07:52:06.000       2016-07-03    USD        CAD         1.2908
    2016-07-02 07:06:08.000       2016-07-02    USD        CAD         1.2915
```

Here is a schema/sample data for Table A which has the WeekStart and WeekEnd Dates:

```
order#      WeekStart                        WeekEnd                    Curr
1256      2016-07-04 00:00:00.000            2016-07-10 00:00:00.000    USD
1255      2016-07-04 00:00:00.000            2016-07-10 00:00:00.000    USD
```

Based on Table B, because the End Date goes into the future, the average rate should be calculated as the following:

```
2016-07-04 ---- Use historical currency
2016-07-05 ---- Use historical currency
2016-07-06 ---- Use historical currency
2016-07-07 ---- Use today's currency rate 
2016-07-08 ---- Use today's currency rate 
2016-07-09 ---- Use today's currency rate 
2016-07-10 ---- Use today's currency rate
```

Then using these rates above, it should return an Average Rate as a column for each of Rows in Table A.

However, if the WeekStart and WeekEnd dates were in the past and less than today's date, then it would just calculate the average for the Start-End using the historical rate in table B.

Am I correct to assume this can be done via function? That would be the best approach. If so what would the function implementation look like.

Comment: You don't need a function you can do it via a query.  So what if start date is prior to today and end date is after should that be averaged or use todays rate?

Comment: Also if you can post your schema it would be good.

Comment: That is the case that is described above.  In this case, exchange rates from today()+1 until end date would be today's exchange rate and it would get the historical date and then average at the end.

Comment: @Matt Please let me know how this can be done via Query.

Comment: No worries I am writing something, I probably should have asked a minute ago but if you have some sample data for the tables it would be good.

Comment: in the first case statement condition change er.[Date]  = to CAST(er.[Date] AS DATE) = because you are trying to compare midnight of today with some random time throughout the day so they are not equal.  But this brings up the question of how many exchange rates will be in your er table for today?  do we need to take an average of those too?

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect your changes to date time.  you may also need to cast the startdate and enddate as a date too depending on what you actually want.  When comparing dates you have to consider if their is time as well.

Comment: I cast the Start And End date too. It seems that Now it only does it until the current today's date. But it still does not cover the case where If the Item is out until July 10. It should join today's exchange rate until the 10th of July. It also seems to be missing the July 4th Join on the ExchangeRate Table. 
http://screenshot.net/0p8d6i0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @ToCurrCode CHAR(3) = 'CAD'

;WITH cteTally AS (
    SELECT 0 AS I
    UNION ALL
    SELECT I + 1 AS I
    FROM
       cteTally
    WHERE i + 1 <= 6
)

SELECT
    a.OrderNum
    ,AVG(b.Rate) AS AvgRate
FROM
    TableA a
    INNER JOIN cteTally t
    ON DATEDIFF(day,a.WeekStart,a.WeekEnd) >= t.I
    LEFT JOIN TableB b
    ON (CASE
          WHEN DATEADD(day,t.i,a.WeekStart) <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) THEN DATEADD(day,t.i,a.WeekStart)
          ELSE CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
       END) = b.[Date]
       AND a.Curr = b.FromCurrCode
       AND b.ToCurrCode = @ToCurrCode
GROUP BY
    a.OrderNum
```

Create a Tally Table with a recursive common table expression [CTE] that will essentially make your 1 week long record into x# of days.  This is 0 based so 6 is actually 7 days.

Join that to the orders to create a row for every day by using.

Join that to your exchange rate table, use a similar case statement to my previous answer that says when the date is >= today then use today's date for the join.  Notice I am using a left join just in case you have missing data.

Then do your aggregation and get your average.

Comment: ??? that will be via parameter. Additionally I am assuming the INNER JOIN can be changed to an outer JOIN as there may be data that is already in the desired currency and will not need any conversion.

Comment: I figured to currency would be a parameter so a table valued function could be good for that.  The inner join can also change to an outer join.  The price calculation will change a little but I will update.

Comment: can you please also explain where it is joining with the latest date from today if the date is in the future and the currency table only has currency from today.

Comment: WHEN a.EndDate >= CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
                 AND er.[Date] = CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) THEN 1 - is saying any time the end date is greater than the start of today AND ExchangeRate Date is today then allow the match

Comment: @Matt...tried it again it seems like there is an issue. 
The Left Join seems to be giving me NULL For DATE. Here is what I am using for the Start and End Date 2016-07-04 00:00:00.000                  2016-07-10 00:00:00.000

Comment: Update your question with what you tried so I can take a look at it.  But you should get some NULL's for date in the case in particular when no conversion is needed, or if the exchange rates are missing.  But date shouldn't be in your result set or your group by won't work and you wont get an average of your rates

Comment: I don't this WHEN CAST(a.WeekEnd AS DATE) >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
                 AND CAST(er.[Date] AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE will work. Because. Essentially For WeekStart and WeekEnd (July 4, July 10) I should see more rows (July 4, 5 , 6 , 7 ,8 9, 10) corresponding to the exchange rate of July 5th.

Comment: no you shouldn't see more rows for 6,7,8,9,10 because those days were after the 5th (today) which you said you wanted anything that had a end date after today to be that days exchange rate. That's what that line does.  At this point if you want me to troubleshoot any further or test you need to provide test data and a desired result.  I am confident my query has the basis for what you need but because I don't know how your dates are handled I am not sure how to tweak the date comparisons a bit more. So if you want further assistance please include a script with test data in your question.

Comment: I don't think I explained this well. So I have edited the question and added a couple of examples. Please take a look. I think this would be done via function rater than a query, but please do let me know.

Comment: you don't need a function.  I changed my answer to reflect the change in your desired logic.

Comment: did you take a look at it?

Comment: Yes I did....Not sure why its doing this...but I am still getting some records without the Rate. I'll post it up in the details.

Comment: Is it possible you do not historically have an exchange rate for every day? And maybe missing for an entire week.  Is so how do you want to identify what that rate should be?

Comment: There are exchange rates for Sunday was previously not available. I believe that may be affecting it.Other than that it seems to be working. Thank you so much for all your self.